# how to fetch data from database using dynamic mysql query by date range

Tags: php, mysql

how to use date range function in this dynamic query for fetch data from database like fetch data from database from date  to date.

```
unset($sql);

    if ($stationFilter) {
        $sql[] = " STATION_NETWORK = '$stationFilter' ";
    }
    if ($verticalFilter) {
        $sql[] = " VERTICAL = '$verticalFilter' ";
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";

    if (!empty($sql)) {
        $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $sql);
    }

    echo $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query to get dates between the range:

```
SELECT  * FROM    tableName WHERE   From_date >= '2019-01-03' AND  To_date   <= '2016-01-09'
```

Add

> AND

condition to after

```
$query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $sql). 'AND From_date >= '2019-01-03' AND
    To_date   <= '2016-01-09'';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like below code

```
unset($sql);

if ($stationFilter) {
    $sql[] = " STATION_NETWORK = '$stationFilter' ";
}
if ($verticalFilter) {
    $sql[] = " VERTICAL = '$verticalFilter' ";
}
if (isset($start_date) && isset($end_date)) {
    $sql[] = " created_at between '".$start_date."' and '".$end_date."'";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";

if (!empty($sql)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $sql);
}

echo $query;
```

Hope it will help you.